# Mail and Message not Dismissing from Alert View

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, message, alert

I have a UIAlertView that launches an email and a messages screen. When a user clicks on the Alert's button, both views open, however, they do not close.

I have a tried adding:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

to the body of the class, however, it did not help.

Here is how the email is presented:

```
    [viewController presentViewController:email animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Edit Here is the entire code I am using to present the email:**

```
//send email...
-(void)sendEmail{

    //mail composer
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if(mailClass != nil){
        if([mailClass canSendMail]){

            //get the current view controller from the App Delegate
            apptester_appDelegate *appDelegate = (apptester_appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            UIViewController *viewController = [appDelegate getViewController];

            MFMailComposeViewController *email = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            email.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            //navigation bar color depends on iOS7 or lower...
            if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
                [[email navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor];
            }else{
                [[email navigationBar] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            }

            //show the model view...
            [viewController presentViewController:email animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this error?

This may not be relevant, but this app has a tab bar.

Comment: And that "class body" is the delegate?

Comment: No, it is just the .m file for the view that launches the Alert View. Do you think I should put it in the App Delegate?

Comment: How are you presenting the VC's?

Comment: No, but the class containing the method you show only has an affect if it's the delegate of the composer view.

Comment: Here is the logic: The alert view is presented from the class with the view controller. The send email and messages are from a class which is the parent class to the view controller. When the alert button is clicked, the method [self sendEmail]; or [self sendMessage]; are called.

Comment: You don't seem to understand.  Those composers need a delegate to work.  You have provided a delegate method, but have you actually wired it up correctly?

Comment: I have already implemented email.mailComposeDelegate = self; and added the above method to the class which presents the modal view controller.

Comment: Finally you answer my question from the first comment.

Comment: Do you think it could be due to the fact that the email is presented as a standard view controller, not a modal view controller?

Comment: FYI - do not check the version number to decide whether to call `setBarTintColor` or not. The proper way is to do: `if ([[email navigationBar] respondsToSelector(@selector(setBarTintColor:)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set delegate for mail controller

```
   mail.mailComposeDelegate = viewController;
```

Also try this as well,

```
    [viewController.tabBarController presentViewController:email animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Have you try this method and pass "controller" instead of self:

```
   -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
    {
       [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I have tried this, and it dismisses when it is not being called from the Alert View. So if I call it from a table view, it is fine, but not from an Alert View. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you please provide your code that presenting from alert view?

Comment: Please see the edit to my original post. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Why was this answer accepted? It's incorrect. You don't set the `delegate` property. There is a different property that needs to be set. See my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy He as already set the delegate as email.mailComposeDelegate = self;

Comment: OK, I didn't notice the updated question. That doesn't change the fact that setting the `delegate` property is not part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is the responsibility of presenting controller to dismiss the modal view. Make sure you implement the delegate of the modal in the presenting controller.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) Make sure you set the `mailComposeDelegate` on the `MFMailComposeViewController` before you present it.

2) In your `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` method, you should do:

```
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```