# dismiss MFMailComposeViewController from SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I open `MFMailComposeViewController` from `SKScene` in this way:

```
-(void)sendmail {

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.delegate = self;
    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nothing@gmail.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:recipients];

    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
}
```

and this works, but after when i want return to `SKScene` the delegate method is not called and are unable to go back.

this is .h of SKScene:

```
 @interface SettingScene : SKScene <UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: Let's Set mailer.mailComposeDelegate while presenting mailer.

Comment: Also please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22458384/mail-and-message-not-dismissing-from-alert-view/22458799#22458799

Comment: @Natarajan wow! I never added this line of code, and it has always worked! i think that is something relative to skscene, because i always wrote only mailer.delegate = self . thanks, if you add your answer i accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set,

```
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

while presenting mailer.